# Sending commands to socket from C# with webbrowser

Tags: c#, java, browser

I'm creating a bot, where i would load this site and open the browser game
i the webbrowser in C# to load the page, and then it loads the java applet. Since the game is partwise based on this java applet and is (through java applet) connected to a socket where it sends the commands. My question is then, how do i "hook" this socket and send commands ? - I know the commands cause i decompiled the java applet, i just don't know the approach of "hooking" the socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question right, it sounds like you have a java applet that is connecting to an IP address somewhere on the Internet and communicating with a server at that IP address through a socket.

If this is the case, you can't hook into the socket per se. What you can do is use a network sniffer such as [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to find out what the IP Address or server name is that its communicating with. Then you can edit your [Hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) and point the IP Address that the applet is using to point to 127.0.0.1, which is your local machine.

After doing that, you can make a TCP/IP Server that runs on your local machine and you can have it do whatever you need. Look [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server) for an example on how to make a TCP/IP server in C#.